# PHP multi sort by different conditions using an external array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [time] => FOUR_DAY
            [zones] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [time] => THREE_DAY
            [zones] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [time] => ONE_DAY
            [zones] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [time] => ONE_DAY
            [zones] => 2
        )
)
```

What I need is to

1- Sort by the 'time' field, using

```
$time = array('ONE_DAY','TWO_DAYS','THREE_DAYS','FOUR_DAYS','FIVE_DAYS');
```

2- Then sort the above result by 'Zones' in ASC order.

Expected Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [time] => ONE_DAY
            [zones] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [time] => ONE_DAY
            [zones] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [time] => THREE_DAY
            [zones] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [time] => FOUR_DAY
            [zones] => 25
        )
)
```

Please help me with a good option. I had tried with `usort` for the 'time' field and `multi_sort` functions. But stuck still.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That's great that you tried with usort. But show the code that you've tried. Then we will try to fix it.

Comment: What determines the sort order for items at indexes 0 and 1 in your desired result?  Is `id` a third sort criteria, or do you care if the sort order on id may be unpredictable? Have you considered defining `ONE_DAY`, `TWO_DAY`, etc. as constants so they are easier to sort with?

Comment: @dragoste: I used this code for the 'time' sort as per my requirement. <br> usort($myArray, function ($a, $b) use ($time) { $pos_a = array_search($a['time'], $time);
  $pos_b = array_search($b['time'], $time);
  return $pos_a - $pos_b;
       });

Comment: @MikeBrant: The get the array from an API, which I have like to the way I had described above. And yeah, no need care if the sort order on id. I just need to sort first by 'time' and then by 'zone' in ASC order. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All!! I finally found a solution for my problem.
As **$time** is with pre-defined values, 
Replaced

```
$time = array('ONE_DAY','TWO_DAYS','THREE_DAYS','FOUR_DAYS','FIVE_DAYS');
```

AS

```
$time = array(1=>'ONE_DAY',2=>'TWO_DAYS',3=>'THREE_DAYS',4=>'FOUR_DAYS',5=>'FIVE_DAYS');
```

And used **array_multisort** instead of **usort**

```
    `foreach($myArray as $key=>$response){`enter code here`
       $sortNumber = array_search($response['time'],$time);
       $myArray [$key]['numericTimes'] = ($sortNumber)?$sortNumber:"NULL";
       $sortByTime[$key] = array_search($response['time'],$time);
       $sortBtZone[$key] = $response['zones'];
     }`    
array_multisort($sortByTime, SORT_ASC, $sortBtZone, SORT_ASC, $myArray);
```

Hope this helps for someone at some point!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `usort` for this job.

Try something like:

```
$sorted = usort($notSorted, function($a, $b) {
    //array of times to compare
    $time = array('ONE_DAY','TWO_DAYS','THREE_DAYS','FOUR_DAYS','FIVE_DAYS');

    //check index of time in $times array
    $aKey = array_search($a['time'], $times);
    $bKey = array_search($b['time'], $times);

    //if the same - then compare by zones;
    if($aKey == $bkey) {
       return $a['zones'] - $b['zones'];
    //else compare by time's indexes
    } else {
      return ($aKey-$bKey);
    }
});
```

Not tested by shows the idea.

Check details for [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) in PHP manual

Answer (score 0):

```
  $order = array("ONE_DAY","TWO_DAY","THREE_DAY","FOUR_DAY");

  $test[4] =array("id"=>21,"time"=>"FOUR_DAY","zones"=>25);
  $test[1] =array("id"=>20,"time"=>"THREE_DAY","zones"=> 2);
  $test[2] =array("id"=>22,"time"=>"ONE_DAY","zones"=>2);
  $test[3] =array("id"=>24,"time"=>"ONE_DAY","zones"=>2);      

  $newarray=array();
  foreach($test as $kk=>$t){
    $newarray[$kk]=$t["time"];      
  }      

  $final=array();      
  foreach($order as $key=>$f){  
   $mykey=array_keys($newarray,$f);


   if(is_array($mykey)){
      foreach($mykey as $key){
        $final[]=$test[$key];
      }
   }   

  }  

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($final);
  echo "</pre>";
```